# Does anyone remember this game from the seventies?

Tags: identify-this-game

This might be a tough one. My mom and dad are trying to remember the name of a game they played before I was born (I am 36 so we’re going back). All they can remember is that it was a card game, it had a plastic board with slots that you put the cards into, lying down flat. They can’t remember if they were face up or face down. They think it was sort of a solitaire type game, but for two players. I know this is not a lot to go on. Google is failing me so far.

Comment: This question can use some extra information. 
Ordinary cards or special cards?

Comment: Are you certain that the game was limited to 2 players? Could it be for 2 to 4 players and your parents only played it as a 2-player game? This type of information would be useful because a 2-player limit excludes many games, one of which might be the one you're looking for. For example, it might be «Probe», a 2 to 4 players game that fulfills your minimal requirements. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2060/probe

Answer (score 2):

I agree with comment that the question really needs more details but based on what you've said I will assume your describing [Guess Who](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4143/guess-who)

It fits your description in following ways...

It came out in 1979 and was certainly around when I was a child and I'm only a little older than you.

The game board had plastic slots in which meant you could have cards standing up or face down.

It was a two player game that was really each player playing their own solitaire game until one of them won.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that vaguely matches your description is [Rack-o](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/917/rack-o)

Comment: Rack-O was a favorite with my family.  The racks had no provision for cards to lie flat; they could only sit vertically in the racks.

Comment: I agree with Racko.  While the cards do not lay flat as @ZeissIkon pointed out, the OP indicated we are talking about 36+ years of, possibly false, memory.